# Parameter Error in my Login Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

There is an error in my Login Controller, which I cannot figure out why. The error is for the line

```
Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumber);
```

it underlines db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumber); and say cannot implicitly convert type 'RMS.Models.Login' to RMS.Login

I made sure that I am using the correct table fields. Note: when typing the intellisence brings up "Logins" instead of "Login". It doesn't bring any errors for that part though

here is the rest of the code
Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RMS.DAL;
using RMS.Models;

namespace RMS.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        RMSContext db = new RMSContext();


        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(Login model, int? LoginStudentNumber, string LoginPassword)
        {
            //Login user = db.Logins
            Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumber);


            if (user == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid User Id");

                return View(model);
            }



            if (user.LoginPassword.Equals(LoginPassword))
            {

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Password");
            return View(model);

        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model RMS.Models.Login

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Creative - Bootstrap 3 Responsive Admin Template">
    <meta name="author" content="GeeksLabs">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Creative, Dashboard, Admin, Template, Theme, Bootstrap, Responsive, Retina, Minimal">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">

    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- bootstrap theme -->

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--external css-->
    <!-- font icon -->

    <link href="~/Content/elegant-icons-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Custom styles -->

    <link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body style="background-color:white">
    <img src="~/img/thrupps.png" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; margin: 0px 490px 0px 490px; " />
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="login-wrap">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "login-form" }))
            {
                <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
                <div>
                    @ViewBag.Name1
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginStudentNumber, "LoginStudentNumber", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginStudentNumber, "LoginStudentNumber", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", type = "number" })
                </div>
                <div>
                    @ViewBag.Name2
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.LoginPassword, "LoginPassword", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <input type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block " value="Login" />

                @Html.ValidationSummary()

            }
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace RMS.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
        public int LoginID { get; set; }
        [Required]        
        public string LoginStudentNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]        
        public string LoginPassword { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: IT would be useful if you posted your Login model.

Comment: You try to use 2 different types even if they both have the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in your controller:

```
using Login = RMS.Models.Login;
```

This will tell controller, that you want to use your RMS.Models.Login in account controller for Login class. Or change explicitly where you want to use that model to this:

```
RMS.Models.Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because this line

```
Login user = db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumber);
```

`db.Logins.Find()` is returning `RMS.Models.Login` type and you are attempting to assign it to the type of `RMS.Login`

If you do this:

```
var user = db.Logins.Find(LoginStudentNumber);
```

It will fix that error as it will be implicitly typed. But you will probally get other errors due to it not being the type you expect.

What you need to do is map the value of `user` to the type of `RMS.Login`